Power PC G4 assembly language programming question
Edit: I suddenly realized that I can write a C Hello World and look at the disassembled code if I have the tool. I'll see what I get.
I'm trying to write a simple Hello World program using an iBook G4 (Mac OS X with XCode 2.5), assembled by GNU assembler 1.38.
Surprisingly, there is VERY LITTLE material online for this architecture, even compared to CPUs from decades earlier such as 68K (yeah I know it was popular but PowerPC has been popular for a while too). All the IBM links are down, and even archive.org doesn't work because IBM just loves to redirect spiders I guess. There is only the more advanced 64-bit AIX stuff I think. The only book I could find is the "Programming the PowerPC (1994)" but it doesn't talk about assembly programming. There is also the NXP PowerPC 601 manual, but I don't understand it (more details below).
Anyway, I asked ChatGPT to write a program, and wasn't able to compile it after many hours of correcting (For a good laugh, I spent 30 mins convincing myself and ChatGPT that it actually should use ; instead of # for comments -> which I already knew years ago but it happened that the error message was very ambiguous and ChatGPT was so confident of it, so I didn't even think of it in the beginning).  Here is the most current version:
.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _start
_start:
    # Write "Hello, World!" to stdout
    li r0, 4              ; System call number: write (Mac syscall table)
    li r3, 1              ; File descriptor: stdout
    lis r4, hello@ha      ; Load the high part of "hello" address into r4
    addi r4, r4, hello@l  ; Add the low part to r4
    li r5, 14             ; Length of the string
    sc                    ; Trigger the syscall

    # Exit the program
    li r0, 1              ; System call number: exit (Mac syscall table)
    li r3, 0              ; Exit status
    sc                    ; Trigger the syscall

.section __TEXT,__cstring
hello:
    .asciz "Hello, World!\n"

Error message (for the lis and addi lines):

Parameter error: expression must be absolute (parameter 2)
Invalid mnemonic 'ha'

I managed to remove all errors except for the @ha and @l part -- I did find such examples on the Internet (e.g. in the as manual or on Godbolt if I use Power GCC) so I figured maybe it's just a PowerPC error. The NXP manual somehow doesn't even show a load SIMM to Register instruction (looks like all loads look like this: li RA, d(RC)). I think I must have missed something.
Can you please let me know how to correct those two lines? And more importantly, can you please point me to a book or a website for some iBook4 assembly language programming tutorial? Prefer textbooks but manuals work too.

There is a PowerPC Hello, World! example on this page and also on this page.

Apple also produced an assembler reference guide for PowerPC and i386 which is relevant to the age of your machine, although it does not have the code examples that you need.

I think this leans towards being one of the “bad” debugging questions.

... and debugging a program written by ChatGPT, not a human!

I don't know a PowerPC from a hole in the ground, but 5 minutes googling suggests OSX uses 'ha16' and 'lo16'.

Plus, the title has the format “⟨TOPIC⟩ question”, which is a no-no.

The ChatGPT generated code looks like the example code @NoelWhitemore linked, but with 'r' prefixed before all the registers.  AIUI, the PPC standard uses bare numbers for registers (Godbolt -- or gcc -S -- does the same).  gas has an -mregnames flag which might allow r0, etc (or perhaps  %r0).

@KelvinSherlock The 'r' prefix should be fine for Mac PowerPC code as these registers are referred to in that form in the Apple assembler reference guide I linked to. The r prefix is probably needed to differentiate the general purpose registers from the floating point registers (which have identical numbering schemes, 0-31).

Thanks @NoelWhitemore I see it is also using the @ha and @l mnemonics. Might have something to do with my as switches...need to drill into it tonight.

@NicholasHumphrey There's a book from 1995 called "Optimizing PowerPC Code" by Gary Kacmarcik that you might want to track down as it's specifically for assembly language programming.

I never use the actual ChatGPT but use several other coding LLMs. I find them much worse at assembly and BASIC than most languages because there's less training material for them in a useable state online and there are many conflicting dialects and versions used by different platforms and compilers even changing over the years.

The following code works and the ori r0, r0, 0 section stops a segmentation fault after "Hello World" has been printed to the terminal:
.data

HelloWorldString:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"
    len = . - HelloWorldString

.text

.globl _start

_start:
    # Load all the arguments for write()
    li r0, 4 ; syscall number (write)
    li r3, 1 ; syscall arguments (stdout)
    lis r4, ha16(HelloWorldString) ; load upper 16 bits of address
    addi r4, r4, lo16(HelloWorldString) ; add lower 16 bits of address
    li r5, len ; length of string
    sc ; call kernel
    ori r0, r0, 0 ; equivalent to NOP and needed to handle Mac OS system calls correctly 

    # Exit the program
    li r0, 1 ; syscall number (exit)
    li r3, 0 ; return status code 0 (program terminated normally)
    sc ; call kernel

I then assembled this code with
as -arch ppc helloworld.asm

and linked it like this
ld -arch ppc -e _start a.out -o helloworld

Your mileage may vary! I'm assuming the segfault was either a memory issue or I wasn't making the system calls correctly and it was fixed using the example on this page.

Mac OS X Internals page 570 explains it.  In the libc stubs, the sc is followed by an unconditional call to cerror() which sets errno, ie, sc ; bl cerror   If the call succeeds, errno shouldn't be set so srr0 -- the return pc address -- is incremented to skip over that instruction.  This is MacOS-specific behavior.

Thank you, that makes sense - that behavior sounds a little bit too clever for its own good, but I see the logic in doing that. So that would presumably mean that the reason my code was segfaulting originally was because li r0, 1 was being skipped over and the following command made no sense when sc was called?

I think the sys call only clobbers r3 and r4 (for the return value), and of course the pc, so if the li r0, 1 would be skipped and you would effectively be doing something like write(0, NULL, 12), then dropping off into who knows what. That's my theory anyway. If you have truss (when was that added?) you could see what syscalls are happening.

Thanks. I've no idea how old truss is but it looks like it got replaced by dtruss sometime around OS X 10.5 which is the version I'm running on my G5.

I actually typed dtruss but the auto-correct didn't approve.  sudo dtruss *program-name* will print out the systems.

The output from dtruss matches what you said, that a second call to write() is attempted but with invalid values that causes a crash. In the working version of the code, I expected to see a system call for exiting the program but there was nothing after the write() call? Anyway, thank you for explaining that. I've ordered a copy of Mac OS X Internals so I can timewarp back to 2006 :)
